# How to fill a polygon with a repeatable image cropped from a texture?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I know that this can be achieved easily by using GL_REPEAT for a given texture and mapping texture coordinates appropriately onto the vertices. I'm wondering however if it's possible to do the same not for a whole texture but just image cropped from it? The only way seems to me to create a separate texture programmatically to fit the image and then using it... Is there any better solution?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the question, isn't this just a matter of manipulating the uv coordinates? Scale the uv range to match the crop width and height, and then add the correct offset of the crop-rectangle relative to the texture's uv-origin. In the shader you can select/discard the pixels you want to render based on the fragCoord, and do more border-matching there too if you want the final result to include the borders.

Comment: hmm I guess it wouldn't work. Take a big rectangle for example 1024x600px consisting of 4 vertices. Let's say I want to fill it with an image 32x32px. In case of such image cropped from a texture, 4 vertices of a destination rectangle are not enough to map texture coordinates appropriately to fill entire rectangle uniformly. In case of a full texture it is possible becouse of no additional offsets... That's what I think at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your large source texture has dimensions Tx, Ty

Let's say your cropping area dimension is tx, ty with an offset ox,oy. (in your case, tx,ty would be 32x32)

Let's say the destination quad has UV space [0..1, 0..1] ( in your case the quad is 1024x600 in unit size)

- First you need to compute in the fragment shader the (u,v) of the actual fragment. The values will be in the of the UV space of the destination quad.

  (su,sv) = (u,v)
- Multiply by the dimension of the quad (transforming this into pixel units)

  (su,sv) = (u,v) * (1024,600)
- This will be used to sample from the cropped region, so truncate to the crop area dimension first, and offset the cropped window to the source texture position

  (su,sv) = ((u,v) * (1024,600)) % (32,32) + (ox,oy)
- Bring it back into coordinates for the source position quad for sampling, also in the  [0..1,0..1]

  (su,sv) = (((u,v) * (1024,600)) % (32,32) + (ox,oy)) / (Tx, Ty)

So now when you write the glsl shader you can use this to find a pixel in the cropped window that matches the one you want, for every fragment. The truncation operation '%' will make it repeating over and over again as the fragment (u,v) rises to 1 for every fragment.

```
color = texture(sampler, (su,sv))
```

Comment: ok now I quite understand your approach. I haven't tried it yet but it looks promising. Would it be possible to extend this approach for any polygon? not just a rectangular quad?

Comment: I figured it out! Just a matter of uv manipulation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I ended up using such a line of code (pseudocode) in my fragment shader to calculate appropriate UV coordinates from my texture atlas: uv.xy = (vertex_position.xy % image_size.xy + image_offset.xy) / tex_size.xy;
This however introduces spaces between tiles no matter what I do. I tried extending the image size by 1 px or shrinking it to take only the area that's not affected by blending but the problem persists. I guess it has sth to do with floating point precision so do you think it could be somehow fixed? When using whole texture with GL_REPEAT to fill polygon there's no such a problem

Comment: If it is floating point precision, it's a good idea to make sure the values you work with are in the [-1000, 1000] range. Here your mantissa will have enough bits to represent most of the natural numbers with enough accuracy so that rounding them gives the correct result. This is  especially true when adding/subtracting or doing modulo (%). Atleast as important is the notion of sampling at the center of a texel, so if you have 1024 pixels in width, the first pixel should be sampled at  (0.5, 0.5), not at 0.